# $f(A)=0 \iff A$ is not invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse

> Let $f: M_n(\mathbb{K}) \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $\forall A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{K}) : f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$ and $f$ not constant.
>
> Prove that: $f(A)=0 \iff A$ is not invertible.

I can also show that $f$ is injective.

Comment: **HINT**: What is $f(I)$ if $f$ is not identically $0$?

Comment: I forgot to add: $f$ is not constant.

Comment: $f(A)=f(A)f(I) \implies f(I)=1$ if $f(A)\neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true as stated. The function $f(X)=0 \forall X$ is a counterexample.

**With the extra assumption** that $f$ is not constant function, the claim holds. Here are the hints:

*Hint 1:* Show $f(0)=0$.

*Hint 2:* If $f(Y) \neq 0$ for some $Y$ set $A=Y, B=I$. Deduce that $f(I) \neq 0$.

*Hint 3:* If $A$ is invertible set $B=A^{-1}$.

*Hint 4:* If $A$ is a diagonal matrix with $n-1$ ones and a zero on the diagonal, show that $f(A)=0$.

To do this, consider all such matrices $A_1,..., A_n$. Show that for each $j$ there exists some $P$ such that $A_j=PA_1P^{-1}$, and deduce that $f(A_j)=f(A_1)$.

What is $f(A_1...A_n)=?$

*Hint 5* Use hint $4$ to deduce that if $A$ is a diagonal matrix with at least a zero on diagonal then $f(A)=0$.

**Hint 6:** If $A$ is not invertible show that there exists some $D,B$ with $D$ diagonal and $B$ invertible so that $A=DB$.

Comment: What is $A_i$? A matrix with i zeros

Comment: @MathBuster As I said $A_1,.., A_n$ are all matrices with one zero and n-1 ones on the diagonal. You can call $A_i$ the one with zero in the ith possition.

Comment: Thanks! I did it! $f(A_1\dots A_n)=0$ so $f(A_1)=0$, then we can use the reduced echelon form of $A$.